# Why setFrame increases the reference count of layer?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Executing this code:

```
mainLyr = [[CALayer layer] retain];
[mainLyr setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,23.0,23.0)];
```

in debugger, I found that after `retain`, the reference count of `mainLyr` is 2. This is correct.

But after `setFrame`, the reference count increased to 3. Why? And how to find out if a method will increase or decrease the reference count (can not find that in reference manual).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been said many times on stackoverflow, don't rely on the refcount for your memory management. Follow the [memory management rules](http://www.stepwise.com/Articles/Technical/HoldMe.html) and you'll do just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Graham is correct, but the reason it increments the reference count is that you're using Core Animation here; a layer's frame change is animated, and during the animation the target object is retained. After the animation duration (by default 0.25 sec, I believe) your reference count should drop back by 1.